# Use segment appsflyer package to the flutter app

Tags: android, ios, flutter, appsflyer, segment-io

I am trying to use this: https://segment.com/docs/connections/destinations/catalog/appsflyer/ to my flutter app, they have an option for iOS and Android but not for flutter, can anyone help me here